# How to create regex where there can be specific char between characters in pattern and I have one "wildcard" char?

Tags: python, regex

I want to create regex in python where I'm given a substring and I want to find it in my string. Characters in substring and my string are always either D, T or F. There are two conditions for match:

1. After every character in given substring there can occur char '-' (I don't know how to approach this one especially)
2. Every character can be either the character I'm looking at or 'X' so X is a "wildcard" (I know I can use '|' for that so it would be I believe ([DTF]|X))

So what I mean is if I'm given DTTFDD as substring other proper matches would be:

- D**-**TTFDD
- D**X**TFDD

Edit: These matches can occur in bigger string such as FTDTTDFD**D-TTFXD**TFTFD

How can I put all of this together?

Comment: Does after every char means you can have multiple hyphens? Even after the very last character? Also, is there any maximum on the usage of the wildcard "X" and must there at least be a single character D, T or F found in the substring?

Comment: Yes, I can have multiple hyphens, but the clue is that when I omit them the sequence of char is the same: D-T-TF-D-D is still a match, bc when I exclude the hyphens sequence is DTTFDD. There is no maximum on the usage of X, so XXXXXX still matches DTTFDD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you could try:

```
[DX]-?(?:[TX]-?){2}[FX]-?(?:[DX]-?){2}
```

See the online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/DLRtJQ/1)

- `[DX]-?` - A literal "D" or "X" followed by an optional hyphen.
- `(?:` - Open non-capture group:

  - `[TX]-?` - A literal "T" or "X" followed by an optional hyphen.
  - `){2}` - Close non-capture group and match twice.
- `[FX]-?` - A literal "F" or "X" followed by an optional hyphen.
- `(?:` - Open non-capture group:

  - `[DX]-?` - A literal "D" or "X" followed by an optional hyphen.
  - `){2}` - Close non-capture group and match twice.

A little less verbose without the non-capture groups:

```
[DX]-?[TX]-?[TX]-?[FX]-?[DX]-?[DX]-?
```

Comment: thank you for such useful link and explenation! that definietly helped me understand, I believe it does desired thing I described